# How to take the username and password of a user to register in GitHub via the API?

Tags: android, github-api

I am trying to create a simple app, where, after registration, you end up in your github account.

Which parameter in the request should the password substitute?

I though of using this one:

https://api.github.com/users/whatever?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy'

but it is only the username used here, followed by the authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which parameter in the request should the password substitute?

From the [API OAuth documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/):

> `client_secret`: The client secret you received from GitHub when you registered.

So you should not use the GitHub account and password, only the application secret credential.

Comment: Thank you! But the idea is that on the first screen, you enter your name and pass, a login form. Then you are supposed to end up on the site. How to take the credentials? Or you mean, that the login itself should be done via is and secret, and they to be passed as params?

Comment: @user6456773 no, the secret is more for the app itself to be allowed to invoked the GitHub API. For the user credentials, that would be the job of smart lock (https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/, https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials)

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot!